# How to store user input in an int array

Tags: c++, arrays, string, char

I need to ask the user to input 8  zip codes and then store them in an array of integers and then to output them one by one , each being in a new line.These two things should be done in separate functions. But when it runs the code first time it shows only menu, then second time in loop when i enter L and input 8 zipcodes it shows this error 
Enter your choice: libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::out_of_range: basic_string(in here optionInChar=optionInString.at(0);)

```
using namespace std;

void DisplayCityZipCodes();
int LoadCityZipCodes(int ZipCodes[],int SIZE);
void DisplayCityZipCodes(int ZipCodes[],int SIZE);
void DisplayMenu();
char GetOption();

int main(){

int const SIZE=8;
int ZipCodes[SIZE]={0};

bool moreWork=true;



option=GetOption();

 while(moreWork) {

  DisplayMenu();

 option=GetOption();

  switch(option){

     case 'L':
    ZipCodes[SIZE]= LoadCityZipCodes(ZipCodes,  SIZE);

     break;

        cout<<"D";
     case 'D': DisplayCityZipCodes(ZipCodes,  SIZE);
     break;

   }
 }
}

void DisplayMenu(){
cout<<"       **********************\n\n";

cout<<"       San Jose City Zip codes\n\n";

cout<<"       **********************\n\n";

cout<<"1. Load City zip codes\n";
cout<<"2. Display all City zip codes\n";
cout<<"3. Search a City zip code\n";
cout<<"4. Reverse the City zip code List\n";
cout<<"5. Quit\n";

}

char GetOption(){
string optionInString="";
char optionInChar='a';
cout<<"\n\nEnter your choice: ";
getline(cin,optionInString);
optionInChar=optionInString.at(0);
cout<<"\n";
return optionInChar;

  }



int LoadCityZipCodes(int  ZipCodes[],int  SIZE){

cout<<"PLease enter 8 city Zip Codes ";
int i=0;
for(;i<8;i=i+1){
cin >>ZipCodes[i];
}
return ZipCodes[i];


}

void DisplayCityZipCodes(int ZipCodes[],int SIZE){
int i=0;
for(;i<8;i=i+1){
cout<<ZipCodes[i]<<endl;
}


}
```

Comment: You are trying to do several things at once. Try to tackle them separately first, and let us know which ones give you trouble.

Comment: Or run in a debugger to locate the crash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now I have not had a hand on C++ for a long time, but this will work.
You should look on the variable declarations and some other things though.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>

using namespace std;

void DisplayCityZipCodes();
void LoadCityZipCodes();
void DisplayMenu();
int const SIZE = 8;
int ZipCodes[SIZE];

int main()
{
    DisplayMenu();
    return 0;
}

void DisplayMenu()
{
    int ch;
    cout << "       **********************\n\n";
    cout << "       San Jose City Zip codes\n\n";
    cout << "       **********************\n\n";
    do
    {

        cout << "1. Load City zip codes\n";
        cout << "2. Display all City zip codes\n";
        cout << "3. Search a City zip code\n";
        cout << "4. Reverse the City zip code List\n";
        cout << "5. Quit\n";

        cout << "\nPlease enter your choice:";
        cin >> ch;
        switch (ch)
        {
        case 1:
            LoadCityZipCodes();
            break;
        case 2:
            DisplayCityZipCodes();
            break;
        case 5:
            exit(0);   //You will need to include math.h for this.
        default:
            cout << "please enter a proper choice!";
            break;
        }
    } while (1);

}

void LoadCityZipCodes()
{
    cout << "PLease enter 8 city Zip Codes ";
    for (int i=0; i<8; i++)
    {
        cin >> ZipCodes[i];
    }

}

void DisplayCityZipCodes()
{
    for (int i=0; i<8; i++)
    {
        cout << ZipCodes[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

You can add remaining of your functions with case 3 and 4.
Try to debug the code and see how it work before you post :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, you really helped!  Also can you please explain why you put do and while(1) statement? I was confused on while (1)part. Also, do you know of a way to check if the user entered zipcodes first and if he did not to show him an invalid data message. I am thinking of assaigning boolean and making it true when 1 is entered first and false when it is not. But it gets confusing since second time around in a loop I would probably go for case 2. Thank you again for all the help!!

Comment: Ok,
Its logic, 1 means TRUE condition
so when you use a do {}while(TRUE); you can not exit the loop or come out of it. The only way to exit the loop when you enter choice 5. Which will exit the program (exit(0)). So unless and until you enter 5, you can not actually exit the program :)

Comment: Don't call me that :) you are always welcome! You can accept the answer BTW if you got what you want by ticking it

Answer (score 1):

You need to look closer at the statements

```
return ZipCodes[i];
```

and

```
ZipCodes[SIZE]= LoadCityZipCodes(ZipCodes,  SIZE);
```

In both cases you use `ZipCodes[8]` which is definitely out of range.

To solve both problems, don't return anything from `LoadCityZipCodes` (i.e. make it return `void`), because it already sets the values in the array.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remeber that when programming we start counting at 0. That means for an array that has the size 8 all the valid indexes are: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7. When you try to access your array with ZipCodes[8] you are asking for the 9th element which is out of range.